# How to speed up excel spreadsheet creation. currently its cell by cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to speed up the generation process of an Excel spreadsheet with openpyxl.
If possible I want to stay with openpyxl.

Currently my data arrays ~3x4500 are put into the sheet cell by cell one at a time.

```
 for n in range(0,len(headers)):
        worksheet.cell(row=1, column=worksheet.max_column + 1).value = headers[n]
        for i in range(0,len(dataarraylist[n])):
            worksheet.cell(row=2+i, column=worksheet.max_column).value = dataarraylist[n][i]
```

For some reason it takes 22 seconds to begin with, then the time requirement increases significantly with  the next array.
So its 20s then 40s, 60s, 90s and so forth.
Is there a way to put in whole columns or even such a 3x4500 arrays in excel with way less time?

[image]

Sorry if this question feels dumb I am new to bigger spreadsheets and could not find anything related to bulk paste-ins for Excel with openpyxl.

Edit:

switching it to append (as suggested below) I lost a little bit of control where exactly to put in the data but I gained speed which is sufficient for me now.

I changed the code:

```
def write_asset_position_data_in_spreadsheet(dataarraylist):
    t=time.time()
    headers = ['ID','Name','Position']
    path=str(pathlib.Path().absolute())
    wb = load_workbook(path+"/Aalizer.xlsx")
    worksheet = wb.active
    for i in range(0,3):
        worksheet.append([headers[i]]+dataarraylist[i])
    print('Extracted',len(dataarraylist)*len(dataarraylist[0]),"new entries\nThis took",time.time()-t,"seconds")
    worksheet.title = "Analizer"
    wb.save(path+"/Analizer.xlsx")
```

This leads to the following speed results

[image]

Of course. This time requirement also scales with more and more data but for now this is sufficient.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it before, don't have it here, but as per RealPython:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

rows = [
    ["Product", "Online", "Store"],
    [1, 30, 45],
    [2, 40, 30],
    [3, 40, 25],
    [4, 50, 30],
    ]

for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)
```

Hopefully a bit quicker than addressing each cell separately - and definitely more succinct for your code.

Comment: Yes. Thats a delightful way.
Tried this.
I failed to figure out how to tell the append method exactly where to put the array.
I need to add another array from time to time.
Append just appends it below the last line.

Comment: Sorry, just did a time check - unfortunately its far quicker addressing each cell separately than sending the row in.

Using the same 1000 square 2D list of randoms goes in around 10 times quicker when addressing each cell individually than appending a row. :-(

Comment: Append only adds below the lowest existing entry - so if you've headers in row1, it'll start in cell A2 - that make sense?

Comment: No. Actually you were right. I switched to rowwise operation with append and its quicker. See above

Comment: Actually, it won't be quicker than going cell by cell, because openpyxl does this for you in the background. But it's certainly cleaner and less likely to be a source of bugs.

Comment: Is is normal that it takes significantly longer with  more data in the sheet?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Every time you open a file you have convert from XML to Python and then back to XML when you save it, so the more data you have the longer it takes.